# building a quiz game in c#

Tags: user-input

Forgive me, as I am new to c sharp, and programming in general. I am trying to make a quiz game, and am hoping that someone might point me in the right direction.

So here's the program would do...
When the user starts the program, he/she has two options:

1. to create a category, such as history, family, football,...and so on.
2. To Play the Game, at which point the user would select a previously created category from which the questions would arise.

So if I am the user, and I click on "Create a new category", I am taken to a screen where I can do just that. I enter "Family". And now I have the option of creating subcategories of family. For instance the subcategories might be my family members, so I can have Bobby, Mike, Suzy, mom, and dad.

Once I have created these subcategories, I can click on any one of them, and enter questions about that specific one. If I click on dad, I make a list of questions like, "What year was dad born?", what is Dad's favorite food?", " Where does dad work?", etc.
And for each of these questions, I enter the answer.

So after making the category and subcategories I go back to the main page and click "play Game", and then choose the Family" category. When the game starts, it will pick randomly from the subcategories, and questions about them randomly.

For instance, the program picks Dad, displays "Dad" in a large text box. Under the large text box is the question that the program has selected from the subcategory "Dad". If it asks, "What is dad's favorite food", then the user must type in, "Beef Stew". after answering, and being right or wrong, the program then randomly selects another subcategory, and so forth, and so on

I am using visual studio for this project, and I know how to set up the user interface, but I seem to be confusing myself concerning the user data. Do I need to store the user input in a database? If so what process do I use to recall the information so the program access it and implement it in the game? Do I store it as lists, arrays, collections? If so, what do I need to do to re-implement those lists, arrays, or collections back into the programs code?

I'm really hoping to get an explanation, in words, of what steps I need to take to create this program. Like I said, I'm a newb. So if you can just give me a list of steps, I'll gather the relevant instructions for those steps from my c# books. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: (If the "question" can't fit in the title, then the post is likely not focused enough for SO. The "Programmer" stack might be a better fit, but I do not know.)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to store the questions somewhere (except in memorry) if you still want to have them wenn you restart the program.

Create a Question-Class wich stores the question and the possible answers, ...

When the user creates a new question you create a new Object from that class with the information that the user typed in. Then you will have to store this question somewhere. The best solution would propably be a database.
Create a database in wich you insert all the questions the user created.

When the user then wants to play the quiz you query all the questions from the seleced category and store them in memory(use something like a DataTable).

You can then choose a random question out of the table.

 And that should be it.

 Google the following topics for more information: database, sql, C# database, DataTable, ...